# How to copy file from lumen storage folder to laravel storage

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

i need one help , I couldn't figure out solution for this for copying  file from lumen storage folder to laravel storage folder. As I have app whose api I'm doing with lumen and web part with Laravel. One of my api is used to upload file , which I'm storing it in lumen storage folder but I have planned to make a copy of it to Laravel storage folder and unlink the one from Lumen .

I have used this code given below in Lumen , but its not working .

```
Storage::put($filename,  File::get($file));
$mkcopy_src=Storage::copy($filename, '/data/html/xyzapi/storage/app/public/media/'.$filename);
```

Comment: you can create APIs in Laravel too using [Laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport)

Comment: Define "not working". What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Webinion That has absolutely no relevance to the question.

Answer (score 0):

These aren’t the answers you’re going to like.

**1. Fix your design**

Your two applications shouldn’t be able to talk to each other at a server level. This breaks the API design you’ve created.

By introducing `/data/html/xyzapi/`, you’re also making it server dependant, which means that the app is no longer portable.

If you need to transfer something from the API to the app, then I would use an internal API to do that. It’s safer and more scalable. Create end endpoint on the app that will accept the file from the API.

However...

**2. Don’t store in storage**

Storage is only for application storage. At any given time I should be able to delete the contents of your storage folder and your app can recover. (I know that you can link the public folder to storage, but that was not designed for saving user-uploaded files.)

Instead, consider using a cloud service such as [Coudinary](https://cloudinary.com) or one that comes with your host.